# Issue generating MOC files for QT using a makefile

Tags: qt, makefile

Hello i am trying to generate `MOC` files for `QT` using a makeifle.
The problem is a command is executing from somewhere and i can't find from where....
This is my makefile

```
BUILD = Build

### SOURCES ###
SRC = Src/Main\
      Src/DialogBox/DialogBox

### MOC SOURCES ###
MOC_SRC = Src/DialogBox/DialogBox

### OBJECTS ###
OBJ = $(addsuffix .o, $(addprefix $(BUILD)/, $(SRC))) 
OBJ += $(addsuffix .moc.o, $(addprefix $(BUILD)/, $(MOC_SRC)))

### INCLUDES ###
INC = TOO MANY INCLUDES TO PUT HERE....

### LINKER FLAGS ###
LDFLAGS = -LC:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/lib

LDLIBS = -lQt5Quick  -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core
          
### COMPILER FLAGS
CFLAGS = $(INC)

### COMPILER ###
CC = g++

### QT MOC ###
MOC = moc

all: $(BUILD)/test.exe

$(BUILD)/test.exe: $(OBJ)
    @echo LINKING $^
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
    
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo COMPILING $<
    @mkdir -p $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M -MT $@ -o $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(BUILD)/%.moc.cpp: %.h
    @echo MOCCING $<
    $(MOC) $< -o $@
    @echo MOC END
    
-include $(OBJ:.o=.d) 
    
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @echo CLEANING......
    @rm -rf $(BUILD)/Src $(BUILD)/test.exe
```

This is the result:

```
COMPILING Src/Main.cpp
COMPILING Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.cpp
MOCCING Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.h
moc Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.h -o Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp
MOC END
g++    -c -o Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.o Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp
In file included from Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp:10:0:
Build/Src/DialogBox/../../../Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.h:4:19: fatal error: QDialog: No such file or directory
 #include "QDialog"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.o] Error 1
rm Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp
```

Basically i have only two source files: `Main.cpp` and `DialogBox.cpp`.

I want to generate `MOC` file from `DialogBox.h`.

The problem is this command:

`g++    -c -o Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.o Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp`

I don't understand why it's executing...

**EDIT:**

Even after:

```
MOCCING Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.h
moc Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.h -o Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp
MOC END
```

no such file `Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.cpp` exists.Why?

Comment: Because the target being built ultimately depends on `$(OBJ)` and `Build/Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc.o` is a component in `$(OBJ)`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @G.M. But from where is the command coming from?There is no rule with such command.

Comment: But there is.  The rule using `$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp` will match with the stem `%` being `Src/DialogBox/DialogBox.moc` .

Comment: Than why i don't see the includes from $(CFLAGS)?It's not the same commad as:@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

Comment: The point is to generate it with `$(BUILD)/%.moc.cpp: %.h` and compile it with `$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp`.

Comment: Is the `makefile` shown more or less complete?  Why do the items in `$(SRC)` not have a `.cpp` suffix?

Comment: The makefile is complete.This is the only incomplete part:`INC = TOO MANY INCLUDES TO PUT HERE....`

Comment: Then I suspect one or more implicit rules are being invoked since the rules shown won't (I don't think) match your path names.

Comment: Do you know why when i start my executable(windows) an commpand prompt is also launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.As @G.M. suggested in the comments, probably an implicit rule is executing so i decided to write my own to avoid that.
I added this:

```
$(BUILD)/%.moc.o: $(BUILD)/%.moc.cpp
    @echo COMPILING MOC $<
    @mkdir -p $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M -MT $@ -o $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

and everything works fine.

The complete makefile:

```
BUILD = Build

### SOURCES ###
SRC = Src/Main\
      Src/DialogBox/DialogBox

### MOC SOURCES ###
MOC_SRC = Src/DialogBox/DialogBox

### OBJECTS ###
OBJ = $(addsuffix .o, $(addprefix $(BUILD)/, $(SRC))) 
OBJ += $(addsuffix .moc.o, $(addprefix $(BUILD)/, $(MOC_SRC)))

### INCLUDES ###
INC = TOO MANY INCLUDES TO PUT HERE....

### LINKER FLAGS ###
LDFLAGS = -LC:/Qt/5.15.0/mingw81_32/lib

LDLIBS = -lQt5Quick  -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core
          
### COMPILER FLAGS
CFLAGS = $(INC)

### COMPILER ###
CC = g++

### QT MOC ###
MOC = moc

all: $(BUILD)/test.exe

$(BUILD)/test.exe: $(OBJ)
    @echo LINKING $^
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
    
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo COMPILING $<
    @mkdir -p $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M -MT $@ -o $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(BUILD)/%.moc.o: $(BUILD)/%.moc.cpp
    @echo COMPILING MOC $<
    @mkdir -p $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M -MT $@ -o $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
    
$(BUILD)/%.moc.cpp: %.h
    @echo GENERATING MOC $<
    @$(MOC) $< -o $@
    
-include $(OBJ:.o=.d) 
    
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @echo CLEANING......
    @rm -rf $(BUILD)/Src $(BUILD)/test.exe
```

Comment: Off-topic: why `subst` when doing mkdir? you don't seem to be doing that for the other recipes, e.g. clean

Comment: Because windows uses \ and make uses /.I guess it didn't work, and i had to change the slashes.